# Apex property not getting set

Tags: apex, javascript

I am calling an apex method from javascript using an actionFunction. In the apex method i am setting a variable to true. I am using this variable in my javascript.

## Javascript:

```
function fraudCheck1(){
funcCheckFraud();     
var check = {!fraudCheckFlag}; 

if(check == false){
    var c = confirm('Mismatch found. Do you want to continue?');
    if(c == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
 else{            
    return true;
    }
} 

<apex:actionfunction name="funcCheckFraud" action="{!checkFraud}" onComplete="alert('After apex method');"  reRender=""/>
```

## Apex:

```
public void checkFraud() {
    fraudCheckFlag = true;
}
```

`fraudcheckflag` is getting set to true but when I'm using it in my javascript it is always giving false.

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing here.

When you call actionfunction and its doing its processing in the meantime Javascript exceute the remaining code so it will always give you old value. To make this working you need to make few changes

```
function fraudCheck1(){
   funcCheckFraud();  
}
<apex:outputpanel id ="opPanel">
function fraudCheck2(){   
var check = '{!fraudCheckFlag}'; 

if(check == 'false'){
    var c = confirm('Mismatch found. Do you want to continue?');
    if(c == 'true'){
       //call action function here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
 else{
       // or call action function here
        return true;
    }
} 
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:actionfunction name="funcCheckFraud" action="{!checkFraud}" onComplete="fraudCheck2()"  reRender="opPanel"/>
```

Call your Javascript method from your oncomplete of `actionfunction`

and second thing it will gie you strng in javascript so use `''` quote to handle this.

Comment: I am calling fraudCheck1 on button click and if it returns true then  only my form submits. How should i handle this now?

Comment: @KrishGambhir instead of return true. Just call `actionfuntcion` to submit the data.

Comment: where do i call my action function? @TusharSharma

Comment: @KrishGambhir check my updated answer.

Comment: fraudCheckFlag is getting set on call of actionfunction. So ill have to call it before@TusharSharma

Comment: @KrishGambhir in code you are calling tis before after second method.